# Postman regexp - SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, rest, postman

I'm trying to write Postman test and validate personal identification number with regexp. I have validated regexp: `\b((([0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}|[3]{1}[0-1]{1})[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}(.|\n|\t|)[0-9]{5})|[3]{1}[2]{1}[0-9]{4}(.|\n|\t|)[0-9]{5})\b`

Postman test script:

```
    var req = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw);
    pm.expect(req.personnumber).to.match( \b((([0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}|[3]{1}[0-1]{1})[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}(.|\n|\t|)[0-9]{5})|[3]{1}[2]{1}[0-9]{4}(.|\n|\t|)[0-9]{5}\b), "wwww" );
});
```

Postman returns following error while trying to execute test script:
`There was an error in evaluating the test script:  SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

Answer (score 3):

This error `SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` comes from that you forgot about `/` in the beginning and end of regexp:

```js
pm.expect(req.personnumber).to.match( /\b((([0-2]{1}[0-9]{1}|[3]{1}[0-1]{1})[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}[0-9]{1}(.|\n|\t|)[0-9]{5})|[3]{1}[2]{1}[0-9]{4}(.|\n|\t|)[0-9]{5}\b)/, "wwww" );
```